# Using FluentValidation to validate on a collection of Fields (rather than on a validator model)

Tags: validation, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation, blazor, fluentvalidation-2.0

Im trying to see if there is **a way to using FluentValidation without explicitly creating a validation model for every object type** in my application.

Is this technically and currently possible?

**Updated**

To rephrase this, is it possible for FluentValidation to validate Rules WITHOUT a IValidator context? Instead, i would like to pass in the item instance to be validated and use validation Rules which are constructed on-the-fly.

**Resolved**

> I was able to resolve by doing a kind of a hack solution. Here are
>   basic details of what i did:
>
> 1) I created a class (GenericModel) which has a collection of objects
>   representing properties in a model. 2) I created a validator class
>   that inherits from AbstractValidator. 3) Based on
>   GenericModel's collection of "property objects" + additional metadata
>   about each property's validation rules and error messages, i was able
>   to add FluentValues Rules, all at run-time. 4). At the EditForm i
>   handled the OnSubmit event. In that event handler i execute validation
>   via FluentValidation's ValidateAsync() method. 5). Finally, i iterate
>   thru the validation results and update each field with appropriate
>   CSS, error messages, highlighting...etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generic Validator for Model T Using Fluent Validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49108649/generic-validator-for-model-t-using-fluent-validation)

Comment: Is this link useful? https://chrissainty.com/using-fluentvalidation-for-forms-validation-in-razor-components/

Comment: This is the article i used to get started with FL. But it doesnt address the technical issue for validation T type models.

Comment: I tried going thru the 1st article (the answer posted by Steve Harris). But i simply couldnt understand it.

Comment: Please post your edited answered as a seperate answer and mark it as solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve by doing a kind of a hack solution. Here are basic details of what i did:

1. I created a class (GenericModel) which has a collection of objects representing properties in a model.
2. I created a validator class that inherits from AbstractValidator.
3. Based on GenericModel's collection of "property objects" + additional metadata about each property's validation rules and error messages, i was able to add FluentValues Rules, all at run-time.
4. At the EditForm i handled the OnSubmit event. In that event handler i execute validation via FluentValidation's ValidateAsync() method.
5. Finally, i iterate thru the validation results and update each field with appropriate CSS, error messages, highlighting...etc.

Comment: Can you share the codes of this solution?